# What modules and commands would you recommend to create this table?

Tags: latex

What modules, commands or methods would you recommend to create this table?

[image: Table]

I've tried using table generator for Latex but it messes up the vertical text and the multiple lines inside each cell of column 3.

Comment: If you share what you already got on [Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm sure they can help you out. I'm curious, what made you post it here instead?

Comment: I didn't know there was a Latex specific forum!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `tblr` environment of [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package (see the code below). It provides very intuitive interface to create complex tables.

I would however avoid rotated cells. While the first column seems reasonable to have a vertically oriented text, I don't necessarily see the point to rotate anything in the second column. Rotation adds unnecessary complication.

In the code, if you want to try a variation with a mix of different lines which I'd recommend, comment the line of `vlines, hlines,` and uncomment lines starting from `hline{1,Z} = ...`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\newcommand\rotfirst[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}}
\newcommand\rotother[1]{%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{3cm}{\centering #1}}}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec = {*2{Q[c,m]} X[l,m] Q[c,m]},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        vspan=even,
        cell{2}{1} = {r=8}{cmd=\rotfirst},
        cell{2}{2} = {r=2}{cmd=\rotother},
        cell{4}{2} = {r=3}{cmd=\rotother},
        cell{7}{2} = {r=3}{cmd=\rotother},
        % Simple lines
        vlines, hlines,
        %% A mix of thick and thin horizontal lines
        % hline{1,Z} = {wd=0.8pt},
        % hline{2} = {wd=0.5pt},
        % hline{3-Y} = {wd=0.4pt},
    }
    Type & {Organisme\\Declarant} & Nom du produit & ID \\
    Long long long long long long long long long long text
    & AAAA BBBB CCC        & \kant[1][1] & 11111 \\
    &                      & \kant[1][2] & 22222 \\
    & DDDDDD               & \kant[2][1] & 33333 \\
    &                      & \kant[2][2] & 44444 \\
    &                      & \kant[2][3] & 55555 \\
    & {EEEEE\\FFFF}        & \kant[3][1] & 66666 \\
    &                      & \kant[3][2] & 77777 \\
    &                      & \kant[3][3] & 88888
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]